# ChartNew.js - Remove/Hide zero label from Pie Chart

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to remove zero(0) label from pie chart in ChartNew.js.
Can't figure it out.

Below is the example:

```js
var pieData = [
 {
        value: 0,
        color: "sandybrown",
        title: "label1",

    }, 
 {
        value: 10,
        color: "gold",
        title: "label2",

    }, 
 {
        value: 46,
        color: "darkviolet",
        title: "label3",

    }, 
 {
        value: 0,
        color: "green",
        title: "label4",

    },
 {
        value: 33,
        color: "DeepSkyBlue",
        title: "label5",

    }
 
 ];

 var myoptions = { 
 animateRotate : true,
 animateScale : false,
 animationByData : false,
 animationSteps : 50,
 canvasBorders : true,
 canvasBordersWidth : 0,
 canvasBordersColor : "black",
 legend : true,
 inGraphDataShow : true,
 animationEasing: "linear",
 annotateDisplay : true,
 spaceBetweenBar : 5,
 graphTitleFontSize: 18,
 extrapolateMissingData : false 
 };  

    var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData, myoptions);
```

```html
<SCRIPT src='https://rawgit.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/master/ChartNew.js'></SCRIPT>

<canvas id="canvas1" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
```

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/boxxevolution/wb64oL66/2/][1]
```

Im trying to remove label1 and label4 from the chart.

Comment: Add the following line

inGraphDataTmpl: "<%=(v6 > 0 ? v6+' %' : ' ')%>",

in your myoptions and it should work.

Comment: easy one, it works. thanks bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by V-Q-A NGUYEN, add the following line in options,

```
inGraphDataTmpl: "<%=(v6 > 0 ? v6+' %' : ' ')%>",
```